# Failed to generate jwt token for: com.apple.weatherkit.authservice for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, weatherkit

I'm trying to get my current weather in my location, however I get the following:

> Failed to generate jwt token for: com.apple.weatherkit.authservice with error: Error Domain=WeatherDaemon.WDSJWTAuthenticatorServiceListener.Errors Code=2 "(null)"

```
    class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject{

        @Published var currentLocation: CLLocation?
        private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        override init(){
            super.init()
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.delegate = self
    
    }
}
extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    
        guard let location = locations.last, currentLocation == nil else {return}
    
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.currentLocation = location
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                     didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print( "location manager failed with error \(error)" )
    }
}
```

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    let weatherService = WeatherService.shared
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }.task(id: locationManager.currentLocation){
            do{
                if let location = locationManager.currentLocation{
                    let weather = try await weatherService.weather(for: location)
                    print(weather)
                }
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have added weather kit capability to my app info and on the developer portal, what gives?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You also need to enable it on the `Apps services` tab within your `Edit your App ID Configuration` on the developer dashboard - it is not obvious and was not outlined.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! It's amazing this isn't clearer.

Comment: For those of you that are not as Apple Developer Account savvy like me (I am a newb), this was a helpful resource to find that page above: 

https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-identifiers/enable-app-services

Comment: It works for my production environment, but not for my staging environment which uses a different app identifier. It has been registered properly under AppIDs, but there is no actual app in the app store with this identifier. Might this be the reason?

Comment: Ok. I found the solution. In the App ID, there are actually TWO tabs where WeatherKit has to be enabled. On "Capabilities" AND "App Services"

Comment: @waldgeist as if the answer already says that....

Comment: Ah, I wanted to spread this on another question, actually :)